# How the SW layer communicates with TPM?

Tags: rsa, trusted-platform-module

In a system with TPM, an RSA private key is kept secretly by the TPM and no one can access it. When something needs to be decrypted using this key, does the TPM itself decrypt the whole massage? How is this transferred back to the SW calling API?

Comment: This depends on the concrete implementation, but usually you would let the TPM decrypt the symmetric key for hybrid encryption.

Comment: And in this case the decrypted symmetric key is transfered directly in the clear to the calling API?